# php dropdown selectbox using every file in folder as an seperate linked <option>

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, directory

I am trying to create a dropdown selectbox using every (video) file in a directory X as a seperate linked `<option value=""></option>`.

This is my first attempt:

```php
<div align="center">
<form name="box">
<select name="select_clip" id="select_clip">
    <option value="">---Select Clip---</option>

<?php
$folder = "/volume1/folder/clips";
$allfiles = scandir($ordner);
foreach ($allfiles as $file) {
    $fileinfo = pathinfo($folder."/".$file); 
    $size = ceil(filesize($ordner."/".$file)/1048576); 
    if ($file != "." && $file != ".."  && $file != "_notes" && $file != "@eaDir" && $file != "index.html") { 
        while($file != NULL){?>
            <option value="/*Link to file*/ <?php echo $fileinfo['basename'];?>"><?php echo $fileinfo['filename'];?></option>
<?php
        };
    };
};
?> 

    </select>
    <input type="button" name="Submit" value="Watch Now!" onClick="window.open(select_clip.value,'newtab'+select_clip.value)">
    </form>
</div>
```

I know at what point is my mistake but I don't know how to fix it.

If I click the "Watch now" button a new tab appears (as suggested) but the url in the new tab includes an fail. It links the Link correctly but the part after that is wrong:

```
<?php%20echo%20$dateininfo[%27basename%27];?>
```

Comment: please share a sample output that you get and a sample that you expect

Comment: I get this: http://share.mtg-esport.de/Lore/images/UFeJhDypePJcRPvP2sw8bhVaVJX.png and i wat to get this: http://share.mtg-esport.de/Lore/images/Zz9B50n0cA7dpeBo1Tl6YjH6CbT.png

Comment: Please share the HTML output. You may edit the question and append the output at the end

Comment: sry but i don't know what u want :(

Comment: sry i really dont know what u mean

Comment: That's fine. Check how many times the `foreach` loop is executing and how many times you are getting into the `If` condition and the `while` loop. Apply `echo` at some places in the code and view HTML source from the browser to inspect your output. Remove the echo later on! Is there any publically accessible URL where someone can have a look at it?

Comment: Sure you can look have the URL: http://i3.manga-tu.be/Code_Breaker/index2.html

Comment: I can see the `<?php ?>` code in the HTML. Are you running this over a PHP server or just opening the HTML file in the browser? Run this using some server that could run PHP like Apache or Nginx or IIS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend something like this:

```
<?php

if ($handle = opendir('/path/to/files')) {

    $ignoredFiles = array('.', '..', '_notes', '@eaDir', 'index.html');

    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if(in_array(pathinfo($entry, PATHINFO_BASENAME), $ignoredFiles)) continue;
        echo "<option value=\"LinkToFile " . pathinfo($entry, PATHINFO_BASENAME) . "\">" . pathinfo($entry, PATHINFO_FILENAME) . "</option>";
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: Okay first of all: thanks! But with this i got an empty selectbox.

Comment: Try to do some debugging, like var_dump() the $entry to see what it contains. If you inspect the HTML does it contain <option></option> tags within the select element that are blank, or is the select element entirely empty?

Comment: Okay. That was very simple. Your solution is correct and works. My failur was so simple. I named the file `.html` instead of `.php`. So thanks for this.